# ItemRenderer with button: item selected when button clicked

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, itemrenderer

I need to add a button to each item of the list. Here is my ItemRenderer's code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
Item Renderer to render product preview images as thumbnails
-->
<s:ItemRenderer 
            width="200"
            clipAndEnableScrolling="false"
            xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
            xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
            autoDrawBackground="true"
            xmlns:model="com.pms.approvaltool.model.*"
            xmlns:components="com.pms.approvaltool.components.*"
            xmlns:spinner="de.profundus.editor.components.spinner.*">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[


        protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:VGroup 
          width="100%"
          paddingTop="10"
          paddingBottom="10"
          paddingLeft="10"
          paddingRight="10"
          verticalAlign="middle"
          gap="3">

    <s:Label width="100%"
             text="{(data as Page).label}"/>
    <!-- preview item thumbnail -->
    <mx:Image 
              maxWidth="200" maxHeight="150"
              source="{(data as Page).previewUrl}"
              scaleContent="true"
              maintainAspectRatio="true"/>
        <s:Button click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
</s:VGroup>

</s:ItemRenderer>
```

The issue is that when I click on the button the related item becomes selected. How can I avoid this?

Comment: have you tried something like event.currentTarget.selected = false; in the event handler?

Comment: What is the problem if it got selected? If it is because of background you can try in itemRenderer autoDrawBackground=false

Comment: I have some actions to be done when list item selected too. And I don't want them to be done if button is pressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to stop propagation of mouseDown event to the datagrid, if it will work like...

```
<s:Button mouseDown="event.stopPropagation()" />
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly I don't know what is different between mine and yours , but I just tried create your itemrenderer and stopping propagation of mouseDown event is working....

Comment: Looks like I was wrong. At least now I have it with stopImmediatePropagation() call working.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://forums.adobe.com/thread/776750, you can use `event.stopImmediatePropagation`:

```
<s:Button mouseDown="event.stopImmediatePropagation()" />
```

The following SO post might also help:
[Prevent selection of a particular item in spark list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539185/prevent-selection-of-a-particular-item-in-spark-list)

Answer (score 0):

You could access List from button1_clickHandler and set list's selectionIndex to -1. If itemRenderer is inline you can try parentDocument to access parent List.